# MYSQL Query users orders if they used a certain coupon code

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out if a user who used a discount code has ordered after the initial order.

The three tables are: `order`, `user`, `coupon_uses`

From `coupon_uses`, the only data I'm retrieving is users who used code via:

```
SELECT *
FROM coupon_uses
WHERE coupon_id = 21921
```

I would get a return a table with the user ID, order ID, and Coupon they used.

```
ID  Coupon_ID User_ID   Order_ID
11  21921     148871    1448181
21  21921     888381    1448191
31  21921     888411    1448201
41  21921     354311    1448211
51  21921     452671    1448221
61  21921     684791    1448231
```

Now, I need to check the users that are returned in the first query (who used the code) verses the entire `order` table:

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT order.user_id,
COUNT(*) AS Total_Orders
FROM `order`
WHERE `order`.user_id = (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM coupon_uses
    WHERE coupon_id = 21921)
AND order.order_status != "Cancelled"
GROUP BY order.user_id ASC
ORDER BY `order`.orderplaced_ts
```

But I receive Subquery returns more than 1 row.

The desired result would be return a list of user IDs, with the total orders they placed and the date of of the order.

```
User_ID   Total_Orders  Last_Order
148871    17            2015_01_01
888381    19            2015_01_01
888411    3             2015_01_14
354311    5             2015_05_01
452671    99            2015_02_01
684791    213           2015_01_05
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: What do you mean "that are returned"?  You need to provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Don't you think INNER JOIN should followed by ON table1.match_colum = table2.match_column. Can you tell in above query which column you want to equate? Also Can you fill in { } which you intended to put or more details of columns.

Comment: Updated with sample code, code I've tried, and desired output, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.user_id, COUNT(*) AS total_orders
FROM order AS o
INNER JOIN coupon_uses AS c ON o.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE c.coupon_id = 21921
GROUP BY o.user_id
ORDER BY MIN(o.orderplaced_ts)
```

This assumes that a user can only use a coupon once.

Comment: Thank you sir. This is exactly what I needed. Reading this, it seems so rudimentary but I was banging my head against the wall for an hour.